# Hebrew R code transformed into question marks

Tags: r, hebrew

I'm writing an R code using an hebrew dataset. I had no problem loading the hebrew dataset to R, using sys.setlocale, and I've been working on this code for the past few weeks. Anyhow, I thought it would be more convenient to translate some of the lines in the hebrew dataset to english, so I had to use hebrew in the code itself. It worked just fine, until today I opened the code and suddenly all the hebrew transformed into question marks, as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks,
Nir.